# Hudson is failing to check-out from SVN after SVN moved to different location

Tags: svn, hudson

We use Subversion as code repository and Hudson to build and release the project.
Recently SVN has been moved to a different location, but the SVN URL is unchanged. ie, svn://exos-svn/teal/smp/branches/kuai_b0

When I trigger build on HUDSON, it is failing to check out/update source code from SVN with the following error:

**ERROR: Failed to check out svn://exos-svn/teal/smp/branches/kuai_b0
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: SASL(-13): user not found: Password verification failed**

But I can able to update local codebase using Tortoise SVN client and by other means. It is failing when HUDSON tries to update.

-bala -

Comment: Well, it seems like the password verification fails. ;) Was there a certain user for Hudson or something that doesn't exist on the new server anymore? Seems like the authentication config of SVN has changed.

Comment: Even  my SVN credentials did not work, though they worked well when I use tortoiseSVN.

Comment: Is there a way to configure SVN user credetials to HUDSON, other than from HUDSON web UI.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Failing-authentification-for-svn-td3494589.html

> In my ~/.hudson folder i have an xml file for svn scm, this is where hudson/jenkins stores the credentials. ...

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try:

- Wipe out the Workspace. There maybe something in a `.svn` folder somewhere that's causing problems. Wiping the workspace and rebuild to see if that solves your issue.
- If that fails, disable the project. Now log into your Hudson server as the same user that runs Hudson. Go into the working directory, and try running the same checkout command that Hudson tried in its last build that failed. See if the issue is with Hudson, or if it is with Subversion. Most of the time, doing the build from the command line will help you debug errors.